# How to mock a Files static method with Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a method in my utilities:

```
public void createDirectories(final Path root, final Scaffolding scaffolding) throws FileAlreadyExistsException {
    if (Files.exists(root)) {
        throw new FileAlreadyExistsException("Root directory " + root.toString() + " already exists.");
    } else {
        Files.createDirectories(root);
        // Create directories from the scaffolding object
    }
}
```

I want to mock `Files` so I can test to make sure `Files.createDirectories` with the expected fields are called or not.

Can I do this with Mockito? Or do I need to actually create the directories and check for their existence in some tmp folder?

Comment: You need powermockito to mock static methods.

Comment: You may be able to do it with PowerMockito.  Though fwiw, JUnit's TemporaryFolder is designed to assist with this kind of test.

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens it's more than a static method. This is a global class. `Files` is not an instance of my utility class that I can mock and pass it into the class.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth oh I didn't know about that. Reading about it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write something with tdd and have troubles consider it as signal of bad design. You don't need to mock static fields or find some tricky lib for do it. Instead of doing this make entity that represent filesystem and place all methods related to file operations to this class. With this refactor your code will be like that:

```
class UtilClass { //util classes are bad don't do it
    private final FileSystem fileSystem;

    public UtilClass(FileSystem fileSystem) {
        this.fileSystem = fileSystem;
    }


    public void createDirectories(final Path root, final Scaffolding scaffolding) throws FileAlreadyExistsException {
        if (fileSystem.exists(root)) {
            throw new FileAlreadyExistsException("Root directory " + root.toString() + " already exists.");
        } else {
            fileSystem.createDirectories(root);
            // Create directories from the scaffolding object
    }




interface FileSystem {

    boolean exists(Path path);

    void createDirectories(Path path);
}
```

and test class

```
class UtilClassTest {


        @Test(expected = FileAlreadyExistsException.class)
        public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenRootPathExists() {
            FileSystem mockFileSystem = Mockito.mock(FileSystem.class);
            Mockito.when(mockFileSystem.exists(anyPath())).return(true);
            UtilClass util = new UtilClass(mockFileSystem);
            util.createDirectories(mock(Path.class), mock(Scaffolding.class))
        }
    }
```

In your code outside tests replace mock to implementation.

```
class FileSystemImpl implements FileSystem {

    boolean exists(Path path){
        return Files.exists(path);
    }

    createDirectories(Path path){
        return Files.createDirectories(path);
    }

}
```

and you don't need to touch file system in tests or mock static fields.

Comment: And how do you test FileSystemImpl?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sending you an example, which allows you to use the FileSystems Mock in a transparent way

```
@Test
    @ExtendWith(MockfsExtension.class)
    void testExecute_MockFSNew(FileSystem fileSystem) throws Exception {
        
        Path master = Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("/fakedir/conf/java/rest/master"));
        Path homologacao = Files.createDirectories(fileSystem.getPath("/fakedir/conf/java/rest/homologacao"));
        Path dev = Files.createDirectories(fileSystem.getPath("/fakedir/conf/java/rest/dev"));

    }
```

Paths.get return a mock fs, this is done using `Mockito.mockStatic`

It's also injecting FileSystem in paramter

using

```
package br.com.pulse.starter.builder.steps.impl;

import java.nio.file.FileSystem;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.AfterEachCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeEachCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterContext;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolver;
import org.mockito.MockedStatic;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import com.github.marschall.memoryfilesystem.MemoryFileSystemBuilder;

public class MockfsExtension implements BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback , ParameterResolver  {

    MockedStatic<FileSystems> mock;

    private FileSystem fileSystem;

    public FileSystem getFileSystem() {
        return this.fileSystem;
    }


    @Override
    public void beforeEach( ExtensionContext context ) throws Exception {
        this.fileSystem = MemoryFileSystemBuilder.newEmpty().build();
        mock = Mockito.mockStatic(FileSystems.class);

        mock.when(() -> FileSystems.getDefault()).then(invocation -> {
            System.out.println("Requested FakeFs >>>");
            return fileSystem;
        });

    }
    

    @Override
    public void afterEach( ExtensionContext context ) throws Exception {

        if (this.fileSystem != null) {
            this.fileSystem.close();
        }

        mock.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter( ParameterContext parameterContext , ExtensionContext extensionContext ) throws ParameterResolutionException {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveParameter( ParameterContext parameterContext , ExtensionContext extensionContext ) throws ParameterResolutionException {
        return this.fileSystem;
    }

}
```

See:
https://github.com/marschall/memoryfilesystem
https://github.com/marschall/memoryfilesystem/issues/130

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mock static methods with base Mockito, nor, in most cases, should you be, especially one provided by Java. You can mock static methods with PowerMock, but this is a Global core library.

The piece of code you are testing here is whether or not you get an exception if the directory exists. If `Files.exists()` is returning bad results, your program is toast either way. So what you should ultimately be testing is that the flow is being properly followed while depending on a fully implemented `Files` global.

```
@Test
public void testCreateDirectories() {

    File tempFile = new File("test");
    tempFile.delete(); //delete test directory if it exists     
    tempFile.deleteOnExit(); //and again when the test finishes

    Path testPath = tempFile.getPath();

    foo.createDirectories(testPath, mock(Scaffolding.class)); //should create path
    Assert.assertTrue(tempFile.exists());

    try {
        foo.createDirectories(testPath, mock(Scaffolding.class)); //should FAE
        Assert.fail(Should have thrown an FAE exception at this point!);
    }
    catch(FileAlreadyExistsException faee) {
        logger.debug("Expected FAE exception thrown", faee);
    }
}
```

This execution will go through both the true and false path and clean up after itself.

This double execution of the logic tests both paths and is designed to cover the following scenarios if your `if` statement manages to get mucked up.

- boolean works as intended: both calls work, PASS
- boolean is accidentally inverted: 1st call throws FAE, FAIL
- boolean always returns false: 2nd call doesn't throw FAE, FAIL.
- boolean always returns true: 1st call throws FAE, FAIL.